# matlab shape object if function

Tags: matlab, graph, shapes, polygons

I want to make an object move in matlab. My code is of the following nature

```
global stop
stop = 0;
 for frame=1:1:length(t)
    if stop ~= 1
    axes(handles.aaxes)
    cla
    hold on

    if y(frame)<=0
      rectangle('Position',[3,1,3,(0.000001)],'FaceColor','b');
    else
    rectangle('Position',[3,1,3,((y(frame)+0.00000001))],'FaceColor','b');
    end
   hold off 
    axes(handles.graph)
    cla
    hold on
    plot(t,y)
    plot(t(frame),y(frame),'*k')

    end
%     FF(f)=getframe;
%     f=f+1;
end
```

This makes my rectangle move upwards continuously until it settles to a certain height (position y) for my graphical user interface. However i want my rectangle to move downwards instead of upwards (and hence settle to some position y). Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Your example does not function. Please provide a a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The rectangle goes up and settles to a final height y. How do i make it oscillate less?

Comment: Without seeing all code I would assume that the route is set with y and t. The solution would the be to adjust y and t to get the wanted motion. If you have no time control on your frames that could help controlling the velocity.